# How can I add "comments" that don't become part of the code base?

Tags: visual-studio, comments

Often when I am learning a new technology, I like to add verbose comments everywhere, so that if I come back and am confused about something, I can refer back to the comments. However, sometimes comments and certain frameworks (*ahem* React) don't mix well.

I'm looking for, perhaps an extension of some sort, that will allow me to place comments in Visual Studio that will never get placed in the actual source code. Something a la commenting in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a kind of complicated to find, an easy alternative that you can try are the #regions on C# to hide/ show your comments:

```
#region comments
/**
* Some comments here
*/ 
#endregion
public void myMethod(){
//TODO
}
```